# Changing variable value when script is running continually inside the loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Is it possible to change a value when script is running inside a loop?

```
import sys

inputValue = 120

def changeValue(value):
 inputValue = value

def main():
 if inputValue == 0:
  print 'Value is'+str(inputValue)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 while True:
  main()
```

I think to change executing the script `python app.py` calling the function `python app.py changeValue 23` but I dont know how exactly it'd work.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work, but generally using globals is considered bad design.

Comment: Or a bad practice, rather.

Comment: What is the best practice to make a test like this? The script have the intention for detecting changes of some value and trigger another functions.

Comment: Not too familiar with python specific best practices, but you might try an [object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class) has some more good examples of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to control a running program, but to a first approximation all of them involve alternating between doing some work and checking for input. A very simple approach would be something like this:

```py
import string

value = 1

def checkChangeValue():
    newValue = input()
    if newValue.isdigit():
        global value
        value = int(newValue)

def main():
    print("Value is {}".format(value))

def loop():
    main()
    checkChangeValue()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        loop()
```

This runs the `main` function ("do some work") and then `checkChangeValue` ("check for input") over and over. This may not do what you want, though, because `input()` waits for you to type something and hit enter, so it will block the execution of `main`. To get around this you could add threads:

```py
import string
import threading

value = 1

def checkChangeValue():
    global value
    while True:
        newValue = input()
        if newValue.isdigit():
            value = int(newValue)

def main():
    print("Value is {}".format(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=checkChangeValue).start()
    while True:
       main()
```

Either of these methods may work, depending on your needs. For a more sophisticated approach you might look at the [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) library, which lets you interact with your program through keyboard or mouse input.

There are many other different ways of controlling a running program, too! You could communicate with your program through files, pipes, sockets, shared memory, etc. This in general is called "Inter-process communication" or IPC.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `inputValue` as a global variable using the `global` statement inside the `changeValue` function in order for assignment statements to that variable inside the function to be applied to `inputValue` as a global variable; otherwise the assignment would be made to `inputValue` as a variable local to `changeValue` instead:

```
def changeValue(value):
    global inputValue
    inputValue = value
```

Note that any use of a global variable other than for the purpose of read-only application-wide configuration is generally discouraged. You should consider making your global variable a local one and pass it around as a function argument and as a returning value instead, e.g.:

```
import sys

def changeValue(value):
    return value + 1

def main(value):
    value = changeValue(value)
    print('Value is %d' % value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputValue = int(sys.argv[1])
    while True:
        main(inputValue)
```

Comment: How can I call this arg? `python app.py 'number'` ? Considering the script is running

Comment: You can obtain the first argument to the script with `sys.argv[1]`. I've updated the example in my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I don't think this solution fits the bill: the question is how to control a _running_ program. This lets you start the program with a value but then it will just print that value plus one over and over, and nothing you do from outside will change that.